# JSON Server - Using a cronjob to update the database

Tags: node.js, json, json-server

I am trying to create an API using [JSON server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) whereby new data is added programatically at regular intervals.

The aim is to query data from another api every hour and update the database with this new data.

Currently I am following the example in the documentation, with the added use of a node cron module:

```
// index.js
var cron = require('cron').CronJob;

module.exports = () => {
 const data = {
  categories: []
 };

 const job = new cron('*/4 * * * * *', function() {
  const d = new Date();
  data.categories.push(d);

  console.log('array updated')
 });

 job.start();

 return data;
};
```

This does not work, the array remains empty.

I am wondering what a solution would look like to update the database?

My server code looks like this:

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonfetch = require('./index.js');
const server = jsonServer.create()

fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/db.json', JSON.stringify(jsonfetch()));

const router = jsonServer.router('/tmp/db.json')

const options = {
  static: __dirname + '/public'
}

const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults(options)
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

server.use(middlewares)
server.use('/api', router)

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running on ' + port)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this using the npm node-cron library before. Here is a basic example but I also have an es6 class I wrote so I can give you more sophisticated stuff if you want.

```js
import axios from 'axios'

let node_cron = require('node-cron');

node_cron.schedule('* * * * *', async function () {
   // Do your thing here.
}
```

Comment: thanks @banderson but it doesn't appear to be working.. 

I think it is because the data is being returned before the cron job executes in index.js, but returning the data within the cron job breaks the code. 

let node_cron = require('node-cron');

module.exports = () => {
  const data = {
    categories: [
    ]
  };

node_cron.schedule('*/3 * * * * *', async function () {
  data.categories.push('test');
  console.log('pushed')
});
    return data;
};

Comment: @ogot I was able to console log at every cron interval. The problem might be the return statement. Why do you need to return to update the database? You could just do an async await then insert into the db. Chain .catch onto the await and  console log any errors that happen.

Comment: `node_cron.schedule('* * * * *', async function () {
      console.log('Checking connectivity.');
            await axios.post(`${endpoint}`,
            {
                user_email: "banderson@banderson.com"
            },
            {

            })
            .catch((err, res) => {
                console.log('error: ', err);
                console.log('res: ', res.body);
            });  
        });`

Answer (score 0):

In nestJS you can use @nestjs/schedule and @types/cron packages to schedule the API request.

```
 1. npm install --save @nestjs/schedule
 2. npm install --save-dev @types/cron
```

Next add schedule module to the app.module.ts file as below.

```
@Module({
    imports: [
      ScheduleModule.forRoot()
    ]
  )}
```

Then add implement function with below decorator.

```
 @Cron('60 * * * * *')
  public async getAllImges(): Promise<ImagesDto[]> {}
```